# new \ZipArchive extension not working in Drupal module

Tags: drupal-8, php-ziparchive

*Error: Class 'Drupal\checklist_download\Controller\ZipArchive' not found in Drupal\checklist_download\Controller\ChDownloadController->page() (line 42 of modules/checklist_download/src/Controller/ChDownloadController.php).*

**zip extension installed**,
**simple php file on domain working**, but not in module

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive;

$zip->open($archive_name ,ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

       
foreach ($b as $filename => $file) {

$zip->addFile($filename, $file);

}

$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Drupals own "ArchiverManager" for that:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21ArchiverManager.php/8.3.x

```
//Set path to zip-file or create empty Zip-file:
$zip_path =\Drupal::service('file_system')->saveData('','temporary://'.$zip_name.'.zip');
$zip = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.archiver')->getInstance(['filepath' => $zip_path]);

foreach ($b as $filename => $filePath) {
  $zip->add($filePath);
}
```